# What is the scope of a class inside of a class in C++?

Tags: c++, scope

I've written a class that looks like

```
class Mesh {
    public:
        vector<Vertex> vs;
}
```

where `Vertex` is

```
class Vertex {
    public:
        const double x, y, z;
}
```

I have a function which loads a `Mesh` from a file:

```
shared_ptr<Mesh> load_mesh(string filename) {
    //....
    vector<Vertex> vs;
    Vertex v(1, 2, 3);
    vs.push_back(v);
    return shared_ptr<Mesh>(Mesh(vs));
}
```

My questions are concerning the scope of the `Vertex` and the `vector`.

Will one or both go out of scope?

Which (if any) of the alternatives are preferred?

```
class Mesh1 {
    public:
        vector<shared_ptr<Vertex>> vs;
}


class Mesh2 {
    public:
        shared_ptr<vector<Vertex>> vs;
}


class Mesh3 {
    public:
        shared_ptr<vector<shared_ptr<Vertex>>> vs;
}
```

Or is there a better / easier way of handling this?

Comment: Your original should be fine. `push_back` stores a copy of `v` in the local `vs`; and given the way you declared `Mesh`, constructing one should make a copy of the local `vs` along with all of its elements. The local variables will go out of scope and be destroyed, but the copy in `Mesh` is safe.

Comment: Ah, sorry, fixed that. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Seems like you're asking about the scope of objects inside functions, not the scope of classes inside classes.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `std::vector<Vertex>`?

Comment: I suggest you don't add const members to Vertex, and instead create a const Vertex object when necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic structure looks right to me. You are copying the `Vertex` into the `vector` and then copying the `vector` into the `Mesh`. The local copies in the `load_mesh()` function will go out of scope but because you have made a copy that is ok.

At the risk of being accused of premature optimization I would say that unless the `vector` is small all that copying is a little inefficient. There are a number of ways it could be optimized. With C++11, and [move semantics](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-in-c++11.html), you can keep your current structure and just *move* the data:

```
#include <vector>

struct Vertex {
  const double x, y, z;
  Vertex(double _x, double _y, double _z) : x(_x), y(_y), z(_z) {} 
};

struct Mesh {
  std::vector<Vertex> vs;
  Mesh(std::vector<Vertex> _vs) : vs(std::move(_vs)) {}
  Mesh(Mesh&& other) noexcept : vs(std::move(other.vs)) {}  // Move constructor
};

Mesh
loadMesh() {
  //....
  std::vector<Vertex> vs;
  vs.emplace_back(1,2,3);
  return Mesh{std::move(vs)};
}

int main() {
  auto mesh = loadMesh();
}
```

I'm using `emplace_back` instead of `push_back` to construct the `Vertex` in the `vector` in-place and using `std::move` to move the `vector` into `Mesh`.

Returning a `shared_ptr<Mesh>` would be fine but I wanted to show you can also return the `Mesh` by value. The compiler *should* perform [RVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) and there will be no copy ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25963685/3422652)).

Comment: Your Mesh-ctor misses `&&`.

Comment: @Deduplicator, No [I've intentionally used pass-by-value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7592630/is-pass-by-value-a-reasonable-default-in-c11). At the price of only one extra move I only have to define one constructor but can still bind to rvalues or lvalues. Yes, you could restrict to rvalues if you want to.

Comment: @Deduplicator `Mesh` does need a copy, it needs it in it's member variable. Maybe that is a misleading link, try [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21963062/best-way-to-write-constructor-of-a-class-who-holds-a-stl-container-in-c11):

Comment: i'm not sure when or whether move constructor is generated. i would feel more sure of the code if there was an explicitly specified move constructor.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Yeah, but then I would have to define a normal constructor and realistically a copy constructor also. To keep it simple I might just define a normal constructor and rely on `emplace_back`...

Comment: As it happens, Visual C++ 2013 (i.e. version 12.0) generates a copy constructor call for the return in your current code. Just adding `Mesh(Mesh&& other): vs( move( other.vs ) ) {}` fixes this.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf. Oh, that's a bit disappointing. I thought you could rely on RVO. Interesting if I change it to NVRO by creating a local mesh variable it does seem to optimize it. I might create a question about it.